# Wrong sign extension c++/qt

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, sign-extension

I am running the following code on an Desktop x64 Intel architecture (gcc compiler, linux) and on an RaspberryPi Arm (gcc cross compiler).

```
quint32 id;

id=((quint32)ref[1]);
id|=((quint32)ref[2])<<8;
id|=((quint32)ref[3])<<16;
id|=((quint32)ref[4])<<24;
```

where **ref** is a **QByteArray**.

I noticed, that despite of casting quint32 (which is unsigned int) my Pc do the sign extension which causes error, when the given byte is a negative number. My code runs fine on Arm. Why does this happens? **I thought casting should prevent this. Doesn't it?**

```
   id|=((quint32)ref[4])<<24;
```

disassembly:

```
    mov    -0x160(%rbp),%rax
    mov    $0x4,%esi
    mov    %rax,%rdi
    callq  0x425af0 <QByteArray::operator[](int)>
    mov    %rax,%rcx
    mov    %edx,%eax
    mov    %rcx,-0x170(%rbp)
    mov    %eax,-0x168(%rbp)
    mov    -0x170(%rbp),%rax
    mov    %rax,-0x40(%rbp)
    mov    -0x168(%rbp),%rax
    mov    %rax,-0x38(%rbp)
    lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rax
    mov    %rax,%rdi
    callq  0x425aa0 <QByteRef::operator char() const>

    movsbl %al,%eax                                     #sign extension.

    shl    $0x18,%eax
    or     %eax,-0x148(%rbp)
```

I have also noticed, that compiler uses QByteRef return value instead of char. But it should not cause any error i guess.

from [QByteArray](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QByteArray.html) help page :

```
QByteRef    operator[](int i)
char    operator[](int i) const
QByteRef    operator[](uint i)
char    operator[](uint i) const
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems to me you listed the one line that *can't* cause a problem since all sign bits would be shifted off the top.  Otherwise, I can see that there might be a difference between platforms depending on whether the underlying `char` definition is signed or unsigned.

Comment: Why not use QDataStream and read an uint32 from QByteArray that way?

Comment: Indeed the fourth bit cannot cause any error, i've just copied the wrong assembly example. I think, that char signess shouldn't bother me, because casting uint before shifting forces not to use sign extension. Am I wrong? Of course i can use id|=(((quint32)ref[2]) & 0xff)<<8; which solves my problem.

Comment: What Alan Stokes said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When converting from a signed `char` to `unsigned int` (or other larger unsigned type) the language specifies sign extension happens first. To avoid that, cast the `char` to `unsigned char` as your first step. You shouldn't need any other cast - the increase in size should happen automatically.